# Handle Power BI report publishing using Automation

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I need to publish my power BI reports in multiple workspaces, To publish the same manually is a very lengthy task , I tried crating a Power shell script using CMDLETS but unfortunately I am not getting any API to Re-Publish the already published report,

I have prepared below code in power shell , which will automatically fetch all the  PBIX files and ask user to select the workspace to publish the reports, but I am getting error at "Publish-PowerBIReport" because this is not a valid API , Can anyone please help me out.

```
Import-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

# Authenticate with your Power BI account
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount

# Prompt the user to select a target workspace
$workspaces = Get-PowerBIWorkspace | Select-Object Id, Name | Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select Target Workspace"
$selectedWorkspaceId = $workspaces.Id

# Get the current folder as the source folder
$folderPath = $PSScriptRoot

# Get all .pbix files from the current folder
$pbixFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter "*.pbix" -File

# Iterate through each .pbix file and publish to the selected workspace
foreach ($pbixFile in $pbixFiles) {
    Write-Host "Publishing $($pbixFile.Name) to workspace $($workspaces | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $selectedWorkspaceId }).Name"
    Publish-PowerBIReport -Path $pbixFile.FullName -WorkspaceId $selectedWorkspaceId
}

# Disconnect from the Power BI account
Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Comment: See following for list of commands : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.reports/?view=powerbi-ps

Comment: Why do you have to publish so much? Why don't you just publish once ?

Comment: @jdweng I appreciate you sharing the link, but I'm unable to locate a suitable solution within it. I attempted using the "New-PowerBiReport" function, hoping it would overwrite my existing report, but unfortunately, it consistently generates a duplicate report instead.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani: In each release, we have around 30 reports that need to be published across three different workspaces ( if changes required) . Given the manual effort required for this task, I'm reaching out for assistance as it's proving to be quite time-consuming.

Comment: You need a pbix file which you can get using export in my link or in David's cmdlet.

Comment: @AnkitBijlwan, I get it, but Power Bi is meant to be published once and then data are refreshed daily or hourly. At least, my Power BI reports are refreshed hourly. Why do you have to keep publishing them?

Comment: Have you found an solution for your problem? I'm facing the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

"Publish-PowerBIReport" isn't a thing.  Call [New-PowerBiReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.reports/new-powerbireport?view=powerbi-ps) instead.

Comment: I tried New-PowerBiReport but this create a new report in workspace , if the report is already present a new report with same name will get created . I want to replace the published report every time.